# Alternate for android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in Android 13 (Target SDK version 33)

Tags: android, android-tiramisu

I have been going through the migration documentation of Android 13 and found that android:sharedUserId is no longer supported and we have to use either service or content providers for it([Doc link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-all#shared-user-id)). But currently I am using it for making my application as system app using **android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"**. I there any alternate way or anything is possible?